# How to evaluate a multi input/output model in keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I've followed the description on this guide by keras to build the following model with multi-input and multi-output.

```
## define the model
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 128
HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE = 64
BATCH_SIZE = 32
NUM_EPOCHS = 10

# first input model
main_input = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')
embedding = Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_SIZE,
                    input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)(main_input)
lstm_out = LSTM(HIDDEN_LAYER_SIZE)(embedding)
auxiliary_output = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(lstm_out)
# second input model
auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)

main_output = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=[main_output, auxiliary_output])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss={'main_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2})

model.fit([x1train, x2train], [ytrain, ytrain],
                    epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    validation_data=([x1test, x2test], [ytest, ytest]))
```

In the next step, I want to evaluate my model as well. I suggested running this code for it:

```
score, acc = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                            y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

But with that code I am getting the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

So I thought I maybe get a score and accuracy for both outputs and tried this code, too:

```
score1, score2, acc1, acc2 = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                            y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

but now I am getting the error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)"

So what am I doing wrong? I am just interested in the accuracy of my main_output to be honest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From keras documentation for `evaluate` the can be found [here](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate)

> Returns
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics). The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs.

According to your model, if you do `print(model.metrics_names)` you will get `['loss', 'main_output_loss', 'aux_output_loss']`.

The `model.evaluate` produces a scalar of this format, which indicates what each of those numbers you see in the output of `evaluate` method corresponds to.

Hence your code,

```
score1, score2, acc1, acc2 = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                            y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

will result in an error because there are only 3 indices in the scalar and the code expects to find `4`.

Also,

```
score, acc = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                            y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

will result in an error due to the fact there are more values returned by the `evaluate`.

You can do something like this if you want to unpack the result of `evaluate` in your model directly.

```
loss, main_loss, aux_loss = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                            y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Also in your code, I can see `acc1` and `acc2` which makes me assume that you are expecting to evaluate the model accuracy.

Having said that, I can see that you have not used any `metrics` for compilation of the model. If you want to evaluate `acc` of the model then compile your model like this.

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss={'main_output': 'categorical_crossentropy', 'aux_output': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'main_output': 1., 'aux_output': 0.2}, metrics=['acc'])
```

Then on `model.evaluate()` you will get a scalar corresponding to

```
['loss',
 'main_output_loss',
 'aux_output_loss',
 'main_output_acc',
 'aux_output_acc']
```

Hence, you can unpack it like this,

```
loss, main_loss, aux_loss, main_acc, aux_acc = model.evaluate(x={'main_input': x1test, 'aux_input': x2test},
                                y={'main_output': ytest, 'aux_output': ytest},
                                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined in the model compile that you want accuracy, so when you use evaluate the function will return the loss. You have 3 losses here which evaluate returns:

- (1) Weighted averaged loss of (2) and (3), in your case: 1. * (2) +
  0.2 * (3)
- (2) Loss of main_output - categorical_crossentropy
- (3) Loss of aux_output - categorical_crossentropy